# Why can't I add JSON data into my iOS code?

Tags: ios, json

I am new to iOS development and about to create a bucket list from JSON data imported from an API. However, after running the following code, the app always crashes and cannot show the list from API. Can anyone help me on this? I have tried for around 3 hours.

[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PeopleViewController: UITableViewController {
    var people = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://swapi.co/api/people/")
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            print("in here")
            print(data)

            do {
                // Try converting the JSON object to "Foundation Types" (NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, etc.)
                if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {

                    if let results = jsonResult["results"] {
                        // coercing the results object as an NSArray and then storing that in resultsArray
                        let resultsArray = results as! NSArray
                        print(resultsArray.count)
                        print(resultsArray.firstObject)

                        print("JSONRESULTARRAY", resultsArray)
                        for character in resultsArray{
                            if let name = character["name"]{
                                print("CHARACTER NAME", name!)
                                self.people.append(String(name))
                            }
                        }

                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
                }
                } catch {
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return the count of people
        return people.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Create a generic cell
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        // set the default cell label to the corresponding element in the people array
        cell.textLabel?.text = people[indexPath.row]
        // return the cell so that it can be rendered
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know what is your json format? i.e coming from web.

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu There is nothing wrong with the code. The app is simply stopping at a breakpoint set in the debugger.

Comment: @rmaddy: Wrong question ?? Not Crashing . Good luck,Thanks

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu Look at the picture.

Comment: yes, it stops at a breakpoint and won't continue. The app does not show the list from api

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu   http://swapi.co/api/people/     you can see the json data here

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, I shut down breakpoint in debugger and it works!